# Using stored procedures for social ranking with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, stored-procedures

I am working on a social-ranking engine for items within a database. I think I have the logic solved (in my head anyways), and am now working on the implementation. I'm hoping for either an "Ok, this looks about right" or if i'm totally on the wrong track, "Your an idiot, uninstall". Whichever is applicable.

Essentially I have a few tables setup as follows (Much simplified, [...] indicates other columns not shown)

```
Users
id (int, primary)
email (varchar 64)
[...]

Items
id (int, primary)
URI (varchar 128)
date (timestamp)
[...]
rank (int)

Votes
id (int, primary)
user_id
item_id
```

Now, the goal is that when a user is logged in and 'votes' for a particular item, it adds a row into the Votes table, but also updates the item rank automatically behind the scenes using (i'd assume) a stored procedure based on an algorithm similar to other social ranking sites such as reddit's 'hot' and 'top' sorting algorithms.

My own assumption / solution for the problem is to do something like the following:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS updateRank//
CREATE PROCEDURE updateRank(IN itemId INT())
COMMENT 'Generates a new rank and updates the Items table'
BEGIN
   DECLARE  vote_sum,published_date INT DEFAULT 0;

   SELECT COUNT(id) INTO vote_sum,
   FROM Votes
   WHERE item_id = itemId;

   SELECT date INTO published_date
   FROM Items
   WHERE id = itemId;

   SET @o  = log(max(abs(vote_sum), 1), 10);
   SET @ts = published_date - 1307557809;
   SET @r  = round(@0 + 1 * @ts / 45000, 7);

   UPDATE Items
   SET rank = @r
   WHERE id = itemId;
END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Then, in my PDO query add in the following:

```
INSERT INTO Votes (user_id,item_id) values (:userid,:itemid ) CALL updateRank(:itemid);
```

If this looks retarded, it's because i'm pretty green to stored procedures (at best), and a complete noob (at worst).

My questions are basically: Is there a better way to do this? Is my syntax totally out to lunch? Can this be done behind the scenes (ie, not calling the procedure in my query)? And, Should I be using InnoDB or MyISAM as my primary engine? I have reasons to want to use InnoDB for this particular project (at least a few tables), however everything I read seems to tell me to never use InnoDB... that the cons outweigh the pros.

**EDIT**

Recommended to replace

```
SELECT COUNT(id) INTO vote_sum
FROM Votes
WHERE item_id = itemId;
```

With the following

```
SELECT vote_count INTO vote_sum
FROM Votes
WHERE item_id = itemId;
```

Does that make more sense? Then increment the vote_count field instead of simply updating the score?

Comment: There's no need to include [pseudo tags] in your question title.  We have *real* tags here!

Comment: Ok :( i'll hang my head in shame.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you're aware of it, but there's an easier way,

just add Score and VoteCount to your item-entity,

```
new vote:
Score = (Score*VoteCount+NewVote) / (VoteCount + 1) 
VoteCount++;
```

You loose track of which uses has voted on which items but
that could be added as a entity of it's own.

It's a lighter job for your mysql since no count.

//edit

```
items:
  ItemID
  ...
  VoteSum
  VoteCount
  VoteAvg (computed field, Sum/Count, index to sort fast for "five-stars")

Track of votes - to avoid double-votes and let user delete their vote.
votes:
  UserID (PK)
  ItemID (PK)
  Rating
```

On vote:

```
 insert into votes(...
 update item set VoceCount=VotCount+1,VoteSum=VoteSum+X
```

regards,

//t

Comment: Hmm... so in essence when someone 'votes', increment the VoteCount column, if someone 'unvotes' or removes their vote, decrement the column? 

ie: add a new column to the "Items" table called "vote_count".

and replace the "SELECT count(id)" with "SELECT vote_count FROM..." in the first section of my procedure?

Comment: yes and no. no possibility to remove vote wo specifying value if vote since average is all that's stored. see update.